# pass MySQL link to a class method

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop, class

Here is my problem, i have a class with a ave method, i want to pass a Mysql DB link to it, so i create a new object from the class, and call the saveProperty method, and in my main file i created a MySQL connection and saved the link in a var called $db so when i call the method it's link this: saveProperty($db).

but insted of saving the data i get an error:

Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in C:\wamp\www\aqaria\classes\property.php on line 75

Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in C:\wamp\www\aqaria\classes\property.php on line 99

which means that i didn't pass the link right? but how?

here is some of my code:

```
<?php

  class test 
  {




    function saveProperty($db)
    {

        $sql = "<<query goes here>>" 

        mysql_query($sql,$db);

        if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)
        echo "<h3>Data was saved</h3>";
        else
        echo "<h3>Error saving data</h3>";

    }


  }
```

here is the calling code:

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); 
mysql_select_db("aqaria",$db); 
$property = new Property(); 
$property->saveProperty($db);
```

although it would work if i added the gloabl keyword to method of the class i was wondering if i can PASS the link to the database connection?

Comment: Can you also paste the calling code?

Comment: $db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("aqaria",$db);

$property = new Property();   

$property->saveProperty($db);

Comment: *cough* Can you also paste the calling code... **into your question**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with a reference?

Also you might want to use $db in `mysql_affected_rows()`

```
function saveProperty(&$db)
{

    $sql = "<<query goes here>>" 

    mysql_query($sql,$db);

    if(mysql_affected_rows($db)>0)
    echo "<h3>Data was saved</h3>";
    else
    echo "<h3>Error saving data</h3>";

}
```

Comment: previously i was using "&" in the calling of save Property and it didn't work, now when i used it in the declaration of the function it all went fine thanx jake

Answer (score 1):

It is without doubt possible to pass db_links around in methods.

> Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL-Link
>   resource in
>   C:\wamp\www\aqaria\classes\property.php
>   on line 75

Check you database credentials and output with mysql_error()

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the database object in your function.

Add this at the top:

```
global $db;
```

Edit: to pass it into your function you'd do this:

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("aqaria", $db) or die(mysql_error());

agar_add_offer($someDataFromSomewhere, $db);

function aqar_add_offer($data, $db)
{
    $property = new Property();

    //do some data manipulation

    $property->saveProperty($db);
}
```

Comment: ok it worked thanx, i'm new to OOP in php so care to give me a simple explanation?

Comment: but this is only accessing the global $db var, how can i pass a link to the method without using the global var?

Comment: You'd pass it as an argument to the function

Comment: i tried that and it gave me the error above "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource"

Answer (score 0):

I just use global $db in each method of class I need to use mysql.
$db is defined outside of class.

Is there a method I do not have to use 'global $db' also in each method.